# Is it possible to rent a car in the US and return it in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, car-rentals

I plan a trip from NY City - Upstate NY - Buffalo - Niagara Falls - Toronto.
When leaving the City I want to rent a car to get to the different locations, and since I will fly back home from Toronto, it would be great if I could just return my car there.

Is it possible to rent a car in the US, and return it in Canada?

Comment: Yes, but it will be expensive

Comment: One way rentals (even within country) are highly variable in price and availability. Sometimes (as I found) they'll even rent for no premium if you're willing to move a specific gas-guzzler to where they want it. Other times it's expensive, prohibitively expensive or unavailable. In my case I got a pickup truck rather than the compact I reserved.

Comment: Yes, but it is NOT necessarily expensive. Sometimes you get lucky and they have a surplus of cars they are happy to get driven elsewhere.

Comment: It seems that this question lacks basic research? What did you search before asking here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is it possible to rent a car in the US, and return it in Canada?

Yes e.g. https://www.budget.com/en/help/usa-faqs/cross-into-canada:

> Based on availability at each location, one-way rentals to Canada may be allowed. In order to check the availability of such rentals, renters should fill in an online reservation form and set their preferred pickup and drop-off locations.

Comment: I'm actually rather surprised to hear that this is a thing you can do. I would have expected the customs issues to be quite messy (i.e. you're technically importing the car, albeit on behalf of the rental company).

Comment: Not importing, just having it go across the frontier. The rental company will either shuttle it back or have someone do the opposite travel.

Comment: There are some customs law in the EU and around (e.g. the UK, Norway) that allows rental cars to be managed more easily from a customs perspective, I would believe there are some similar ones between the US and Canada

Comment: @Kevin - you're not importing it at all. It's perfectly permitted for a (say) airline, truck company, taxi service, or whatever, to **operate*** vehicles in foreign countries. (Of course, there may be numerous regulations about that.)  You may be thinking of the case where it is **sold** to someone in a new country, which would be an import.

Comment: @Fattie: At least on US customs declarations, they do not ask you about "sold," they ask you about goods that are "staying in the country," regardless of what transactions apply to them.

Comment: K - it's *not* staying in the country. It's just a piece of equipment that Hertz happens to be moving around internationally back and fore.

Comment: @Fattie, They may stay in the country for a while, though. I have been assigned a US-registered rental car for use in Canada only at YYZ at least twice that I recall. It may be my US driver's license that attracted this. The cars were the only ones in the lot having US plates that I could see (making it seem less probable that this was random selection) and I know there are (modest) restrictions on the time and purpose for which a Canadian-licensed driver can drive a foreign registered car in Canada that may cause them to pick out foreign-licensed drivers to take them.

Comment: @Kevin:  Your instinct isn't entirely off-base; until 2012, it was [prohibited for a Canadian resident to bring a US-plated car across the border.](https://ottawacitizen.com/news/local-news/ottawa-man-may-have-driven-change-to-rule-barring-u-s-rental-cars)

Comment: Guys - honestly, it has *no connection whatsoever* to "import". Check with your import/export legal team if you don't believe!  :)  Cheers

Comment: @Fattie: I do not personally employ an import/export legal team for myself, so all I have to go on are the instructions on [Form 6059B](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/CBP%20Form%206059B%20English%20%28Sample%20Watermark%29.pdf), which very clearly state to "Declare all articles that you have acquired abroad and are bringing into the United States" (residents) or to "Declare the value of all articles that will remain in the United States" (visitors). Those instructions plainly would include a rental car, because it was acquired abroad and will remain in the United States.

Comment: (Also, if you want to have a conversation, please use the [comment reply syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to ensure that the other person knows a discussion is taking place.)

Comment: hi @Kevin note that it says ACQUIRED (means "bought"). No connection in any way whatsoever to rental equipment.  Urge you to ask a customs official next time you pass through, show them the form and this internet discussion!  I'm (as I would imagine, many folks on here) knowledgeable about import/export, as, I've had businesses in that field (although I don't currently have a solicitor in that field!!) Cheers

Comment: @Fattie: Acquired means "obtained." If someone gives you a gift, you still have to declare it.

Comment: Acquired means ownership @Kevin - ask at customs about the form next time passing!  cheers!

Comment: @Fattie: You can't smuggle drugs over the border and say "well, those aren't mine," and expect CBP to be OK with it.

Comment: funnily enough it's completely common that there are drug couriers (who work for pharma companies) who move (very expensive) testing samples, bases, etc from plant to plant over borders. it's a similar thing.  if you mean illegal drugs (eg, cocaine, whatever) I have no idea and that doesn't seem to be under discussion. there are in many countries laws that you can't move such and such over certain borders; that is unrelated to import duties and taxes.  (for example there's no "import duty" on lsd or whatever - it's just, completely illegal to be in possession of it heh!)

Answer (score 12):

This is *wildly, wildly, situational* based on "du jour" market requirements of that rental agency.

As you might guess, demand for rental cars changes regionally throughout the year, and rental agencies often must re-position their cars.  For instance, Vail Colorado uses **a lot** more cars during ski season than the rest of the year. Repositioning costs them money - they must pay 4 drivers to move 3 cars (the 4th car brings all back), or hire haulaway companies.

When they price one-way bookings, they account for that.  If your one-way trip relieves them of the need to pay someone to reposition that car, you will get a favorable price.  However if your one-way means they will have *yet another car* they'll need to reposition, the one-way fee will reflect the costs of doing so, and they may even turn your business down flat if they just don't have the capacity.

Of course, it is axiomatic that most people want to move in the direction most people want to move! So most of the time that one-way fee will be quite bad.

Comment: In the 1970s, our church congregation had a money-raising job to shuttle Hertz rental cars from Oxnard, California to Burbank, California almost weekly (58.2 mile trip).  6 to 8 drivers, one drove a passenger van to bring us back home. Lot of fun driving different cars.  Unfortunately, no sports cars back then...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I've done exactly that (with Hertz) a couple of years ago. Wasn't more expensive than usual.

Comment: Note that the expense depends heavily on what the start/end points are, which direction you're going, and the current distribution of rental cars. Rental car companies need to balance car availability at each location, and if there's currently an excess at your destination, then the company may need to "deadhead" your car to another location, which is an extra expense they'll work into the price. In contrast, if there's an excess at your start and a deficiency at your destination, you might effectively get a discount, as they now don't need to pay an employee to make the transfer.

Comment: Yeah, that maybe true, but I didn't really research or investigate it at the time. I just booked online and that's it. Worked just fine. Similarly I was able to drive from Seattle to Vancouver, and on multiple occasions from LA to Vegas or from Vegas to LA (although this is domestically in the US - still one-way cross state lines). I believe the traffic in this areas is high enough for rental companies to be certain that there will be someone willing to take the car back soon enough.